# Correct lookup of cubemap in GLSL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I want to create a local cubemap and store the normal, depth and radiance values on each face. The values are stored in the cubemap, but I can't do the correct lookup. Here is the code :

Create cubemap and initialization.

```
glGenTextures(1, &depthCubeMap);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, depthCubeMap);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGBA32F, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
}

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthCubeMapFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthCubeMapFBO);

glm::mat4 CubeProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.f), 1.f, 0.1f, FarPlane);
std::vector<glm::mat4> CubeViewMatrix;
CubeViewMatrix.push_back(glm::lookAt(CubePos, CubePos + glm::vec3( 1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3( 0.f,-1.f, 0.f)));
CubeViewMatrix.push_back(glm::lookAt(CubePos, CubePos + glm::vec3(-1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3( 0.f,-1.f, 0.f)));
CubeViewMatrix.push_back(glm::lookAt(CubePos, CubePos + glm::vec3( 0.f, 1.f, 0.f), glm::vec3( 0.f, 0.f, 1.f)));
CubeViewMatrix.push_back(glm::lookAt(CubePos, CubePos + glm::vec3( 0.f,-1.f, 0.f), glm::vec3( 0.f, 0.f,-1.f)));
CubeViewMatrix.push_back(glm::lookAt(CubePos, CubePos + glm::vec3( 0.f, 0.f, 1.f), glm::vec3( 0.f,-1.f, 0.f)));
CubeViewMatrix.push_back(glm::lookAt(CubePos, CubePos + glm::vec3( 0.f, 0.f,-1.f), glm::vec3( 0.f,-1.f, 0.f)));

.....

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthCubeMapFBO);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, depthCubeMap, 0);
.....
}
```

Write to cubemap shader.

**Vertex shader**

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 ModelPosition;

void main() {
  gl_Position = CubeProjection * CubeView * vec4(ModelPosition, 1.f);
  WorldPosition = ModelPosition;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 value;

void main() {
  float lightDist = distance(WorldPosition, CubePos) / FarPlane;
  value = vec4(vec3(lightDist), 1.0);
}
```

Main rendering shader.

**Vertex shader**

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 ModelPosition;

void main() {
  gl_Position = MVP * vec4(ModelPosition, 1.f);
  WorldPosition = ModelPosition;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
uniform samplerCube CubeMap;

// cubemap lookup
vec3 fragToCube = WorldPosition - CubePos;
vec3 lookup = texture(CubeMap, fragToCube).xyz;

color = vec4(lookup, 1.f);
```

**Result Image**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/820BV.jpg

When I rendered each face of the cubemap, I confirmed that it rendered correctly. However, the image above is when rendered with the main shader. I think the lookup to the cubemap is wrong, but I'm not sure why.

This code works correctly when I set it to

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

and

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, depthCubeMap, 0);
```

when initializing the cubemap. However, I want to save it as a color value for future use.

Comment: have you tried to normalize the ```fragToCube``` vector ?

Comment: @Draykoon D Normalization did not change the result. And wiki said "The vectors do not have to be normalized." https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Cubemap_Texture#Texture_Access

Comment: you can debug by returning your direction vector ```uv = (normalized(fragToCube)) + 1.0f) / 2.0f; color = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, 0.0, 0.0);``` this way you can see if your cubemap is well centered, some says that you should position its center to your camera which may differ from the world origin.

Comment: @Draykoon D I have confirmed that the center of the cube map is appropriate. Also, I tried changing the camera's position, but the results were not good.

Comment: @Draykoon D Thank you for answering the question. This issue has been resolved by attaching a RenderBuffer.